# How do I find a map route with Azure IoT?

Tags: c#, azure, maps, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am attempting to complete the first tutorial in the Azure IoT learning path but every time I try to make the device find a customer it says "Failed to find map route." in the console. I've followed all the steps, looked over the code and there's no troubleshooting answers for this particular error. The device is connected to my program it just cannot find the map route.

```
static void GetRoute(StateEnum newState)
    {
        // Set the state to ready, until the new route arrives.
        state = StateEnum.ready;

        var req = new RouteRequestDirections
        {
            Query = FormattableString.Invariant($"{currentLat},{currentLon}:{destinationLat},{destinationLon}")
        };
        var directions = azureMapsServices.GetRouteDirections(req).Result;

        if (directions.Error != null || directions.Result == null)
        {
            // Handle any error.
            redMessage("Failed to find map route");
        }
        else
        {
            int nPoints = directions.Result.Routes[0].Legs[0].Points.Length;
            greenMessage($"Route found. Number of points = {nPoints}");

            // Clear the path. Add two points for the start point and destination.
            path = new double[nPoints + 2, 2];
            int c = 0;

            // Start with the current location.
            path[c, 0] = currentLat;
            path[c, 1] = currentLon;
            ++c;

            // Retrieve the route and push the points onto the array.
            for (var n = 0; n < nPoints; n++)
            {
                var x = directions.Result.Routes[0].Legs[0].Points[n].Latitude;
                var y = directions.Result.Routes[0].Legs[0].Points[n].Longitude;
                path[c, 0] = x;
                path[c, 1] = y;
                ++c;
            }

            // Finish with the destination.
            path[c, 0] = destinationLat;
            path[c, 1] = destinationLon;

            // Store the path length and time taken, to calculate the average speed.
            var meters = directions.Result.Routes[0].Summary.LengthInMeters;
            var seconds = directions.Result.Routes[0].Summary.TravelTimeInSeconds;
            var pathSpeed = meters / seconds;

            double distanceApartInMeters;
            double timeForOneSection;

            // Clear the time on the path array. The path array is 1 less than the points array.
            timeOnPath = new double[nPoints + 1];

            // Calculate how much time is required for each section of the path.
            for (var t = 0; t < nPoints + 1; t++)
            {
                // Calculate distance between the two path points, in meters.
                distanceApartInMeters = DistanceInMeters(path[t, 0], path[t, 1], path[t + 1, 0], path[t + 1, 1]);

                // Calculate the time for each section of the path.
                timeForOneSection = distanceApartInMeters / pathSpeed;
                timeOnPath[t] = timeForOneSection;
            }
            truckOnSection = 0;
            truckSectionsCompletedTime = 0;
            timeOnCurrentTask = 0;

            // Update the state now the route has arrived. Either: enroute or returning.
            state = newState;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the code, as we can see you have initialized the variable **directions** as `azureMapsServices.GetRouteDirections(req).Result` and in the if condition you are checking for `directions.Result == null`. Instead of doing that could you try putting `directions == null` or removing **.Result** while initializing the **directions** variable. Check if this helps then I will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the error make sure that:

> The key call within the code above is `var directions = azureMapsServices.GetRouteDirections(req).Result;`. The `directions`
> structure is complex. Consider setting a breakpoint in this method,
> and examining the contents of `directions`.

You can use the below example code to add the direct method to deliver to a customer :

```
static Task<MethodResponse> CmdGoToCustomer(MethodRequest methodRequest, object userContext)
     {
         try
         {
             // Pick up variables from the request payload, with the name specified in IoT Central.
             var payloadString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(methodRequest.Data);
             int customerNumber = Int32.Parse(payloadString);

             // Check for a valid key and customer ID.
             if (customerNumber >= 0 && customerNumber < customer.Length)
             {
                 switch (state)
                 {
                     case StateEnum.dumping:
                     case StateEnum.loading:
                     case StateEnum.delivering:
                         eventText = "Unable to act - " + state;
                         break;

                     case StateEnum.ready:
                     case StateEnum.enroute:
                     case StateEnum.returning:
                         if (contents == ContentsEnum.empty)
                         {
                             eventText = "Unable to act - empty";
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             // Set event only when all is good.
                             eventText = "New customer: " + customerNumber.ToString();

                             destinationLat = customer[customerNumber, 0];
                             destinationLon = customer[customerNumber, 1];

                             // Find route from current position to destination, storing route.
                             GetRoute(StateEnum.enroute);
                         }
                         break;
                 }

                 // Acknowledge the direct method call with a 200 success message.
                 string result = "{\"result\":\"Executed direct method: " + methodRequest.Name + "\"}";
                 return Task.FromResult(new MethodResponse(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result), 200));
             }
             else
             {
                 eventText = $"Invalid customer: {customerNumber}";

                 // Acknowledge the direct method call with a 400 error message.
                 string result = "{\"result\":\"Invalid customer\"}";
                 return Task.FromResult(new MethodResponse(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result), 400));
             }
         }
         catch
         {
             // Acknowledge the direct method call with a 400 error message.
             string result = "{\"result\":\"Invalid call\"}";
             return Task.FromResult(new MethodResponse(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result), 400));
         }
     }
```

For more information please refer this MS TUTORIAL : [Create your first Azure IoT Central App](https://microsoftlearning.github.io/AZ-220-Microsoft-Azure-IoT-Developer/Instructions/Labs/LAB_AK_20-build-with-iot-central.html#exercise-6-test-your-iot-central-device)  &  [Create a programming project for a real device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-your-first-iot-central-app/5-create-real-device-nodejs?pivots=vs-csharp)

MS Q&A:  [Error - Create your first Azure IoT Central app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/134283/error-create-your-first-azure-iot-central-app.html)